# Can a ® so small as to be reduced to a dot confer any legal protection?

Tags: trademark

The Bank of America iPhone app's icon has a very small ® next to the logo (shown below). The ®, barely visible in the blown-up picture below, is reduced to a small, vaguely pinkish dot on any device where the app may be found running, making its interior "R" practically indiscernible.

I am wondering whether the implied presence of this symbol is still capable of carrying any legal force considering that the symbol itself cannot be made out.

[image]

Comment: Presumably, if you kept clicking you would find more prominent versions of the (R) symbol than the one appearing in the thumbnail. You only have to see it once to make it valid.

Comment: ...I think Bank of America may want to reconsider what they shorten their name to

Comment: @ShmuelNewmark: Why? I can't see anything wrong with "BofA", but I'm not a native speaker of English, so any explanation is appreciated.

Comment: @Heinzi I had to google it as well: [bofa](https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/bofa/)

Comment: True story: I worked on the manual for a published GameBoy NASCAR racing game.  The manual was about 5" (12.7cm) square, and the page numbers on the corners were a picture of a racecar with the number on the top.  These were about 3/8" (1cm) on the page.  The car in question was a Pontiac - we had the rights to the image from NASCAR, but no licensing rights from Pontiac.  One job I was forced to do was to remove the Pontiac logo from the car in the image.  This logo was *literally 3 pixels* in the image, nearly microscopic at 600dpi.  Yes, somebody cared that much about it.

Comment: @tim Native English speaker here (non-US). I'd never heard of it either.

Comment: I've been using the app for at least 2 years now and this is the first time I've noticed that ® speck. Now it makes the app icon look like it has a defect, great!

Answer (score 29):

In [united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states) trademark law, [15 U.S.C. § 1111](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/15/1111) provides that:

> **Notice of registration; display with mark; recovery of profits and damages in infringement suit**

> Notwithstanding the provisions of section 1072 of this title, a registrant of a mark registered in the Patent and Trademark Office, may give notice that his mark is registered by displaying with the mark the words "Registered in U.S. Patent and Trademark Office" or "Reg. U.S. Pat. & Tm. Off." or the letter R enclosed within a circle, thus ®; and in any suit for infringement under this chapter by such a registrant failing to give such notice of registration, no profits and no damages shall be recovered under the provisions of this chapter unless the defendant had actual notice of the registration.

Notice that display of the symbol is optional, the registrant  "**may** give notice" by using the phrase or the ® symbol. But if such notice is not given a significant element of damages in case of an infringement is forfeit unless the infringer had "actual notice" of the registration of the mark.

Since the purpose is to give notice that a word, symbol, logo or other indication is in fact a registered mark, making the registration so small that it cannot easily be seen might tend to defeat that purpose. If an infringer claimed not to be aware that an indication was a registered mark, and if the notice was displayed or printed in so small a form that this claim was plausible, it **might** raise an issue in an infringement suit. I have not found any caselaw on the point.

["Finessing the Details of Type: Registered, Trademark, & Copyright Symbols"](https://creativepro.com/finessing-details-type-registered-trademark-copyright-symbols/)  by  Ilene Strizver advises that:

> These symbols are used at so small a size that they should be neutral in appearance, yet clear at the size they will be reproduced at ... when using a ® or a ™ after a word, the size should be adjusted as necessary, independently from the rest of the text, to look clear and legible, yet unobtrusive. Its proportion next to the neighboring word or glyph depends a lot on the final size of each appearance. A general guideline for text is to make these symbols a little smaller than half the x-height. As the type gets larger, the symbols can become proportionately smaller, especially in headlines.

However this is a guide for typesetters and graphic designers, and is not legal advice.

Several sources indicate that a single use of the R-in-a-circle in connection with a particular mark in any given document or set of packaging is sufficient (as is also mentioned in a comment). If elsewhere in the same web site the logo is displayed in a larger size, with a larger version of the symbol, that would probably offer all the protection needed under US law.

This answer is US-centric. Law elsewhere may or may not be similar.

Answer (score 5):

The symbol is an indicator to you that the trademark is registered. Obviously, its registration status does not vary with the size of the symbol, so the mark remains registered.

Of course, trademark protection also requires the holder to take reasonable steps to police infringement. If the holder failed to use the symbol, that would count against him in an infringement action. But you did in fact recognize the symbol, so there's no indication that Bank of America is doing anything less than what it is supposed to do to maintain its protection.

Comment: I wouldn't say that I _recognised_ the "registered" symbol, but I definitely saw that there was something that looks like a very small symbol and would suspect that it would be a "registered" symbol. Especially since it was right where I would but a "registered" symbol. Not sure if that is enough to give protection. It's definitely more than no symbol.

Comment: @bdb484 To which "you" is that an indicator? The trademark owner, or the reader? Either way, how is anything "reduced to a dot" useful? How could that mean anything but that if it came to a legal argument, the court would have to insist that the reader used a magnifying glass?

Comment: "You" refers to OP. The problem with your approach is that the failure to use the symbol on a single occasion or in a single context is not fatal to trademark protection. The BOA mark and the accompanying symbol have been reproduced millions of times, generally in contexts where there symbol is plainly visible. To avoid damages, an infringer would have to persuade the court that this was the only time he ever saw the BOA logo, *and* that he didn't know the dot was the trademark symbol. I know which side of that fight I'd want to be on.

Answer (score -3):

No, it can't, but only because no form of ® confers legal protection, whatever its size. The ® is a statement that your trademark is registered; an affirmation, a claim or confirmation but not a conferment.

Trademarks are just like copyrights and patents… where they exist, it is not the owner's responsibility to advertise them… in the same way it's not a householder or car owner's responsibility to lock the doors, but that doesn't mean it's not a good idea!

The main relevant difference is that copyrights do not, while trademarks and patents do need to be registered - which should show the whole point.

What any of us publishes is automatically copyrighted by the act of publication. It doesn't need to be formally entered into a register because we can show it was published in this medium on that date. The same is not true of patents or trademarks because they might not have been used.

If I think "Splinkiflinge" is a great name but I'm not ready to launch my new gizmo, and perhaps want to keep everything about it under wraps, formal registration protects me from you using the name "Splinkiflinge", in the same way a patent prevents you from making a gizmo with the same characteristics as mine.

In case a court might rule that a copyright/patent/trademark owner failed to  take adequate steps to protect that interest - can anyone give an instance? - it's good and common practice to publish that ownership as widely as possible.

However, that boils down to whether an offender would, should or could have known the situation and those are legal niceties which might affect how much the offender had to pay; not whether something was due.

Comment: There are several errors in this answer. Copyright is obtained on fixation, not on publication. The R-in-a-circle is not just a statement, it is a **notice** to any potential infringer. Its absence significantly impairs the damages available in a US trademerk suit, unless actual notice to the infringer can be proved, which is often hard if not impossible. Otherwise it may be that **no** damages are payable. Use without registration can establish some trademark rights in the US, but not full rights. Registration is lost in the absence of timely use. Failure to defend a trademark may lose it.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Perhaps this answer should have used a tag to indicate its jurisdictional basis. I'm not sure you should have assumed that it applied to the US.

Comment: @Andrew Leach Since the answer did not use a tag, nor mention any jurisdiction in the body, it **purports** to be accurate for all jurisdictions. Copyright is gained on fixation in all Berne countries, which is just about everywhere. I think the effect of omitting ® is the same in many places beside the US, but I am not sure.

Comment: I should add that unlike a trademark, a copyright owner is not required to take any steps to defend or enforce a copyright. So "a court might rule that a copyright/patent/trademark owner failed to take adequate steps to protect that interest" is incorrect for copyright. This is, again, true in all countries party to the Berne Convention.

Comment: The trademark registration symbol is comparable to copyright notice in that it makes it harder for someone to claim innocent violation, right?

Comment: @Barmar  sort of. Under US law, at least, there are significant differences. © is only one kind of evidence to defeat an innocent infringement defense. ® or "actual notice" is essential for TM damages. ® is part of taking steps to protect a mark, required for a trademark, not for a copyright. But there is a degree of similarity.

Comment: @DavidSiegel The way you seem to use the term, “fixation” broadly depends on publication. How else d’you think fixation is established?

Comment: @DavidSiegel If you think the R-in-a-circle is not just a statement, but rather a notice to any potential infringer, why not explain the difference? Sorry to have noticed this, and they are the same thing.

Comment: @DavidSiegel If you see a difference between your “… absence significantly impairs the damages available in a US trademerk suit, unless actual notice to the infringer can be proved, which is often hard if not impossible” and my “copyright/patent/trademark owner failed to take adequate steps to protect that interest” why not explain that difference?

Comment: @DavidSiegel Can you explain how ”You" refers to OP?

The problem with your approach is that no-one suggested failure to use the symbol might be fatal to anything.

The BoA mark and symbol have been reproduced squillions of times. What might matter would be the contexts where the symbol was not plainly visible.

Why a Court might mind this was the only time anyone saw the logo is interesting, not useful.

That anyone didn't know the dot was the trademark symbol would depend not on whether the dot existed, but whether the Court thought Mr Average should have been able to read it…

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Take a recording of a song. Fixation occurs when the performance is recorded to a file in the studio. Publication of the phonorecording would occur when it is made available for sale on an online music store. Copyright attaching at fixation means if the studio staff leaked unauthorized copies of the recording prior to it becoming available for sale, they would violate copyrights.

Comment: @user71659 Jolly good and so what? In your context fixation is a fact, but it's also irrelevant. What matters is solely what can be proved, which is publication.

You might go so far as to slip a recording into a sealed envelope and deposit that with your lawyer and otherwise, how would you establish your copyright? You'd publish it, inarguably establishing both date and content. How could anything else matter?

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin Fixaztion occurse whjen a work is written down, or saved to a computer file, or recorded, or drawn. It can occur **years** before publication, Indeed there have been successful suits for copyright infringement of unpublished works. There are various ways of proving fixation and its date, depending on the detailed facts. That could be a whole separate question.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin a notice has specific legal effect on the person who whom it is addressed, and on others. Also "notice" is the term in statute. That is the difference between notice and statement. "copyright/patent/trademark owner failed to take adequate steps" is incorrect because a copyright holder need not take any steps. and a trademark owner must take very specific steps, including using the symbol or else giving actual personal notice to any potential infringer. I did not use "you" to refer to the OP IIRC. Someone else did, I think. So I can't say how it was intended.

Comment: No court would "rule that a copyright/patent/trademark owner failed to take adequate steps to protect that interest". For copyright and patent, it's irrelevant (beyond the possibility of estoppel). For trademarks, what matters is not what steps the owner took to protect the trademark, but whether it has become generic.

Comment: @Sneftel Not so. See ["Failure To Enforce Trademarks:"](https://www.forbes.com/sites/oliverherzfeld/2013/02/28/failure-to-enforce-trademarks-if-you-snooze-do-you-lose/?sh=70fef15b6c22), ["TM Owner’s Failure to Police"](https://www.mondaq.com/unitedstates/trademark/20107/trademark-owners-failure-to-police-strikes-again) and *Brand, Inc. v. I.O.B. Realty, Inc.*, 2003 (2nd Circuit) where the court siad "Where a senior user delays in enforcing its rights, a junior user may acquire a valid trademark ... enforceable against even the senior user."

Comment: @user71659 Thanks and I confess, that wholly slipped my mind, though while apparently half asleep I myself said "you might go so far as to slip a recording into a sealed envelope and deposit that with your lawyer…"

My half-arsed defence is seeing studio staff leaking unauthorized copies as straight theft… and I claim no view as to whether such theft of intellectual property counts as "real" theft, or "mere" copyright infringement.

Comment: My sincere apologies to anyone misled by my faulty belief that "trademarks are just like copyrights and patents… where they exist, it is not the owner's responsibility to advertise them…"

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Regarding "studio staff leaking unauthorized copies": the making of the unauthorized copies of the instantaneously copyrighted works would be a copyright infringement. Larceny of the physical object goes by who owns it, whether it may be an authorized or unauthorized copy.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin see the following question and its answer on the issue of fixation. https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/64574/is-a-work-copyrighted-on-fixation-or-publication-whats-the-difference-how-is/64575#64575

Comment: @DavidSiegel Thanks and I was hoping to stick where we were.

Let's remember the OQ dealt with whether an ® reduced to a dot could confer any legal protection?

I went too far down the wrong branch, the other being - don't you agree - that a reasonable court would say, what Mr Average saw as reduced to a dot would be  irrelevant except to the extent the reader could be expected to use a magnifying glass? Would the court not go on to say reducing anything to dot size amounted to an attempt to obscure crucial details in small print, however counter-intuitive that would be here?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin The fixation issue was yes only a sidelight on this question, but seemed to me interesting in itself, aside from any trademark issue. Thus it is now a separate question. It is hard to be sure how a, court would view this issue; I found no caselaw exactly on point. But I think the question is not how "mr average" would view it but whether an alleged infringer was given sufficient notice to know that there was a claim of registration. Other instances of the logo would be relevant, esp if it is considered a 'famous" mark. Expectations of one imitating a mark might be higher.

Comment: Yes it is becoming a separate Question and don't you think the court is bound to say both the trademark holder and the reader can be expected to take reasonable care, and no more… which with or without intent to infringe, doesn't include magnifying glasses (or is there other test for what "reduced to the size of a dot means?"